# How to read the selected dropdown list from HTML to javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="repId">REP ID</label> 
  <select name="item" class="form-control " style="font-weight: bold;" ng-model="idDropdown">                                       
    <option value="{{item}}">Select REP ID</option>
    <option ng-repeat="item in columnData" value="{{item}}">{{item}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

I have tried to get the value selected from dropdown list to Javascript. But I am getting undefined. Below is the code which I have tried in Javascript to read the item value.

```js
var repId = $('#item').val();
```

Comment: I am new to frontend development sorry if anything went wrong there.

Comment: `#item` suggests an element with an ID of `item` - the `select` menu above has a `name` attribute of `item`

Comment: I request you to please correct the code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just add `id="item"` to your <select> tag.

Comment: The code you said that you tried looks like jQuery. Are you using jQuery? If so, add the tag to your question

Comment: Sure Thanks. @j08691

Comment: based on the `ng-` attributes you're also using Angular, though that's not directly relevant to the question.  As a side note, using jQuery and Angular together is asking for a bad time.  Those tools have conflicting methods of working with the DOM, they really shouldn't be used together.   In Angular, instead of reading from the form fields in the DOM, you want to be pulling those values from state.  (If I'm talking gibberish you should probably go through some angular tutorials as a first step, or else start with less complex tooling.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have a `label` element with a given `for='repID'` where `repID` **should** be the ID of the input element that the label describes then you can add the ID to the select menu as per the following.

The `change` handler is there simply to illustrate it in action

```js
$('#repId').change(e=>{
  alert(e.target.value)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="repId">REP ID</label>
  
  <select id='repId' name="item" class="form-control " style="font-weight: bold;" ng-model="idDropdown">
    <option value="{{item}}">Select REP ID</option>
    <option ng-repeat="item in columnData" value="{{item}}">{{item}}</option>
    
    <option>Smurf
    <option>Womble
    <option>Clanger
    <option>Moomin
    <option>Muppet
  </select>
</div>
```